# How to add multiple shakeys for Oath 2.0 Client ID in google sign in?

Tags: android, googlesigninaccount

When I integrated google sign in in android, It asked for SHA1 key , I have given my system one.. Everything is fine and working.. But when my team member generate apk on his sytem, Google sign is not working and I don't know where to add his system SHA1 key.. I could not find option to add SHA1 key for Oath 2.o Client id in developer console. and add the same to google gson file

Anyone help me, Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks,

I got answer at below link

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html

Where they explained we can add any oath clients manually in [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).